# msi to exe convertor not working with wpf projects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My client needs a single .exe file instead of .msi file as an output of project.

I am using http://www.msitoexe.com/ to convert msi to exe files.

All simple projects .msi file is easily converted to .exe files and it runs in same way like .msi but when I am converting the .msi files from projects using WPF, the converted .exe shows just a message with various windows installer options.

Is there any better way to convert .msi to .exe or how I can solve this problem of WPF projects.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state what tools you were using.

Assuming the latest versions (VS2012 and WiX) to create installers, just select "Executable Package (exe)" from the dropdown in the project properties of your installer project instead of msi.

Comment: The VS installers were removed in VS2012, so if you use Wix (http://wixtoolset.org/) you will be able to produce executables on demand and be able to transfer your project to VS2012 without extra work once you decide to upgrade.